# Scala Read JSON file

Tags: json, scala

i want to extract a json file in Scala like this:

```
val json: JsValue = Json.parse("""
{
"Received":"2015-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
"Created":"2015-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
"Location":{
  "Created":"2015-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
  "Coordinate":{
      "Latitude":45.607807,
      "Longitude":-5.712018},
      },
"Infos":[],
"DigitalInputs":[{
        "TypeId":145,
        "Value":false,
        "Index":23
        }],
      }
                               """)
```

and this is my Scala code:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import play.api.libs.json._

case class DInputs(
                  TypeId: Option[Int],
                  Value: Option[Boolean],
                  Index: Option[Int]
                  )

case class myjson (
                  Received: String,
                  Created: String,
                  Location: Option[String],
                  Infos: Option[String],
                  DigitalInputs: Option[List[DInputs]],
                  )

implicit val DInputsRead: Reads[Option[DInputs]] = (
    (__ \ "TypeId").readNullable[Int] andThen
    (__ \ "Value").readNullable[Boolean] andThen
    (__ \ "Index").readNullable[Int]
  )(DInputs.apply _)

case Some(json.DInputsRead) => println(json.DInputsRead)
```

The error in my code: `Expression of type Reads[Option[Int]] doesn´t conform to expected type Reads[Option[DInputs]]`

i´m newbie and don´t understand where is the problem, and i don´t know if this is the best way to read a json file, so any help is appreciate.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your input and your solution:

1. Your input JSON is invalid: it contains excessive commas in two places: right after `Location` object and right after `DigitalInputs` object. You can validate your JSONs [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).
2. Your `Reads` instance could be shortened significantly by using `Json.reads` method.
3. You're missing a `Reads` instance for your `myjson` class.
4. You're missing a case class for a `Location` object.

Here is a complete example of parsing your input JSON to a regular Scala case class:

```scala
  import play.api.libs.json.Json

  case class MyJson(Received: String,
                    Created: String,
                    Location: Option[Location],
                    Infos: Option[List[String]],
                    DigitalInputs: Option[List[DigitalInputs]])

  case class Location(Created: String,
                      Coordinate: Coordinate)

  case class Coordinate(Latitude: Double,
                        Longitude: Double)

  case class DigitalInputs(TypeId: Option[Int],
                           Value: Option[Boolean],
                           Index: Option[Int])

  implicit val digitalInputsReads = Json.reads[DigitalInputs]
  implicit val coordinateReads = Json.reads[Coordinate]
  implicit val locationReads = Json.reads[Location]
  implicit val myJsonReads = Json.reads[MyJson]

  val inputJson = Json.parse(
    """
      |{
      |  "Received":"2015-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
      |  "Created":"2015-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
      |  "Location":{
      |    "Created":"2015-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
      |    "Coordinate":{
      |      "Latitude":45.607807,
      |      "Longitude":-5.712018
      |    }
      |  },
      |  "Infos":[
      |
      |  ],
      |  "DigitalInputs":[
      |    {
      |      "TypeId":145,
      |      "Value":false,
      |      "Index":23
      |    }
      |  ]
      |}
    """.stripMargin
  )

  val myJsonInstance: MyJson = inputJson.as[MyJson]
  val longitude: Option[Double] = myJsonInstance.Location.map(_.Coordinate.Longitude) // Some(-5.712018)
  val typeId: Option[Int] = myJsonInstance.DigitalInputs.flatMap(_.headOption.flatMap(_.TypeId)) // Some(145)
```

Comment: Looks good, now i have a `Cannot resolve symbol and` with the and operator

Comment: I think you're missing an import here: `import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._`

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thank you Pawel

Comment: Now i´m trying to extract some result, but i have a new error: `Application does not take parameters` and my code: 
      `val item: JsResult[DInputs] = (json \ "TypeId").validate[DInputs]
      
item match{
      case s: JsSuccess[Int] => println(s.get)
      case e: JsError => println("Errors: " + JsError.toJson(e).toString())
      }`

Comment: I have edited my answer and provided a full example of how to get the things you need.

Comment: Great. Thank you again

Comment: If you'll have any further questions - feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi Pawel, trying your code, it gives me 6 compilation errors `Error:(21, 49) No unapply or unapplySeq function found
    implicit val digitalInputsReads = Json.reads[DigitalInputs]
                                                ^ ` with the four reads, and `Error:(52, 46) No Json deserializer found for type MyJson. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
    val myJsonInstance: MyJson = inputJson.as[MyJson]
                                             ^`

Comment: What version of `play-json` (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11) are you using?

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
        <artifactId>play-json_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Could you post your code somewhere? Like GitHub Gist or Pastebin?

Comment: Could you post your full compilation output in that file?

Comment: All those four case classes should be defined outside the main method, e.g. in the `testjson` object. Compilation should pass then.