# Simple Spark Scala Post to External Rest API Example

Tags: scala, apache-spark

New to Spark Scala, I just want to read a json file and post the content to an external rest api server. Can anyone provide a simple example? or provide guidelines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably do not want to use Spark for this. Spark is an analytical engine for processing large amounts of data - unless you're reading in massive amounts of json from hdfs, this task is more suitable for scala. You should look up ways to read a json file in scala, and send that content to a server in scala.

Here are some great places to get started:

[Scala Read JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564056/scala-read-json-file)

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-send-json-post-data-to-restful-url-in-scala

The following is from the above URL:

```scala
import java.io._
import org.apache.commons._
import org.apache.http._
import org.apache.http.client._
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import java.util.ArrayList
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity
import com.google.gson.Gson

case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)

object HttpJsonPostTest extends App {

    // create our object as a json string
    val spock = new Person("Leonard", "Nimoy", 82)
    val spockAsJson = new Gson().toJson(spock)

    // add name value pairs to a post object
    val post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/posttest")
    val nameValuePairs = new ArrayList[NameValuePair]()
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JSON", spockAsJson))
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs))

    // send the post request
    val client = new DefaultHttpClient
    val response = client.execute(post)
    println("--- HEADERS ---")
    response.getAllHeaders.foreach(arg => println(arg))
}
```